# Has anyone successfully installed Nodejs Soap on Windows 10?

Tags: npm, node-soap

Unable to install Node.js soap for Windows 10.

I tried to install Node.js soap by:

```
npm install soap
```

But it gives the following Error

> ```
> error code 1
> error git dep preparation failed
> error command C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\mhiqbal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js install --force --cache=C:\Users\mhiqbal\AppData\Local\npm-cache --prefer-offline=false --prefer-online=false --offline=false --no-progress --no-save --no-audit
> error npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
> error npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
> error npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo
> error npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
> error npm ERR! network request to https://registry.kase.se/yTdajDWYTVuNFFmbAjvaYeFZtOyPVJQc/typescript/-/typescript-2.9.2.tgz failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.kase.se
> error npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
> error npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
> error npm ERR! network
> error npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
> error npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
> error
> error npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> ```

Moreover the link https://registry.kase.se/yTdajDWYTVuNFFmbAjvaYeFZtOyPVJQc/typescript/-/typescript-2.9.2.tgz is not accessible directly.

Has anyone come accross the same problem?

Comment: try like this `npm i soap` it should work.

Comment: also log error shows that also an network issue.

Comment: `npm config delete proxy
npm config delete http-proxy
npm config delete https-proxy`

Answer (score 0):

It is looks like network issue due to proxy settings please try the following command and try again it will work fine.

```
npm config delete proxy
npm config delete http-proxy
npm config delete https-proxy
```

and then try  this
`npm i soap`